# Signals and Filters 101

Tags: filters, signal-analysis

I am a complete novice to the world of signal processing, and I am an environmental engineering grad by degree (i.e. zero background in signals/systems). We acquired a couple sensors and a data recorder at work and I am required to analyze the data we measure. Pertaining to that, I have two questions:

1. Is anyone here familiar with Engineering Data Management software by Crystal Instruments?
2. I just need to learn the basic nuts and bolts of signals without having to go in depth into the math of deriving the Fourier Transform or signal design etc. Is that a possibility, and what is a good resource for this?

Comment: your first question makes no sense here. your second question is far too broad.

Comment: Perhaps DSP.SE could be more useful to you if you were to ask a specific "signal processing" question? Like, what is it that you are trying to do with this data? What is the objective?

Answer (score 1):

> I just need to learn the basic nuts and bolts of signals without having to go in depth into the math of deriving the Fourier Transform or signal design etc. Is that a possibility, and what is a good resource for this?

Sorry, I don't think it works this way. Without a proper understanding of the fundamentals, it's unlikely what you will every get useful results of your analysis. Check https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/filters/ or http://www.dspguide.com/ for starters. This is good too, if you are up for it https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-007-signals-and-systems-spring-2011/introduction/